# Service launches my application again and hangs the requesting application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to make my program provide a service to look up words. It works when I drag some text onto the icon but when I try to use the menu item it opens another instance of the application, freezes the application I sent the request from for about 30 seconds and then doesn't execute the method it was supposed to.

Here is my method:

```
- (void)serviceQuery:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error {

    // Test for strings on the pasteboard.
    NSArray *classes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString class]];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];

    if (![pboard canReadObjectForClasses:classes options:options]) {
        *error = NSLocalizedString(@"Error: couldn't encrypt text.",
                                   @"pboard couldn't give string.");
        return;
    }

    NSString *baseURL = @"http://labs.valtyrorn.com/bin/leit.php?q=";
    NSString *q = [pboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
    NSString * encoded = [q stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURL, encoded];

    [webView setMainFrameURL:query];
    NSLog(query);
}
```

and the service part of the plist looks like this:

```
<key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSStringPboardType</string>
        </array>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>serviceQuery</string>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Fáðu beygingarlýsingu</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSPortName</key>
        <string>BIN</string>
        <key>NSRequiredContext</key>
        <dict></dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: Please take a sample of each of your application's processes (and of the hung application while you're at it) and edit your question to include them.